# jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

**Problem:** I am loading a modal form from an ajax call. Within the modal, I have a span element holding an email address.  I am needing to capture the value of the span element in javascript. Currently, I have a button click that calls a function to obtain the text.

Code to read text:

    `function AccountHistoryRedeemSendEmail(emailType)
    {
      clearNotifications();
      console.log('Hit AccountHistoryRedeemSendEmail');
      var url = "../../utility/account/ajaxAccountHistoryRedeemSendEmail.aspx";
        var params = "eType" + emailType;
            //console.log($('#lblHRedeemEmailAddress'));
            console.log('Output text: ' + $('#lblHRedeemEmailAddress').text());
            params += "&HRedeemEmailAddress=" + $("#lblHRedeemEmailAddress").text();
            params += "&timestamp=" + new Date();
    //    new Ajax.Request(
    //        url,
    //        {
    //            method: "get",
    //            parameters: params,
    //            onSuccess: parseAjaxResponseAccountHistoryRedeemSendEmail
    //        }
    //    );
    }`

The error being returned is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null "

I understand the error is telling me  `$('#lblHRedeemEmailAddress')`  is returning a null. Naturally, I have verified my element name to be correct. I have also inspected the element in chrome and verified it is present in the document. Here is html in the document:

```
<span id="lblHRedeemEmailAddress">name@domain.com</span>
```

`< img src="sendemail.jpg" id="SendEmail" alt="Email Certificate" onclick="AccountHistoryRedeemSendEmail('lblEmail');">`

So, the question: Why is my lblHRedeemEmailAddress element null when I try to access it from the function? And, how do I fix this?

Comment: looks like `$` is not referring to jQuery try `jQuery('#lblHRedeemEmailAddress').text()` instead

Comment: Arun, that was the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `lblHRedeemEmailAddress` didn't exist, jQuery would return an empty result set, upon which you would still be able to call `text`. `$` is probably referring to some other library, such as [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/).

Read up on [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) or create a closure where `$` is set to `jQuery`:

```
(function($) {
   // for anything in here, $ will be jQuery
})(jQuery);
```