# Wordpress JavaScript TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme, and I am trying to hide/replace a sentence "One Cikanlari" using the following code in the theme custom JS and also tried a plugin called custom CSS and JS:

URL: http://rahafinsaat.com/?lang=tr

```
 $('h6.snipe.status span').text(function(_,txt) {
return txt.replace('ÖNE ÇIKANLARI', ' ');
});
```

The above when put in the theme custom JS results in the following error in the browser's console:

```
    ?lang=tr:127 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
    at ?lang=tr:127
    at dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
(anonymous) @ ?lang=tr:127
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
```

Tried also this in the custom CSS and JS plugin:

```
jQuery('h6.snipe.status span').text(function(_,txt) {
return txt.replace('ÖNE ÇIKANLARI', '');
});
```

The above gives no errors but the word "ÖNE ÇIKANLARI" Still shows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547324/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-text-of-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First thing, Your selector is wrong.
- Second thing, There is multiple jQuery loaded in your website.
- And the last, You are tring to replace text in uppercase but actually it's in lowercase.

Try this...

```
var jq1124 = jQuery.noConflict();

jq1124(document).ready(function() {
    jq1124('h6.snipe span').text(function(_, txt) {
        return txt.replace('öne çikanlari', '');
    });
})
```

Or Using pure javascript...

```
var titleEle = document.querySelector("h6.snipe span");
titleEle.textContent = titleEle.textContent.replace('öne çikanlari', '');
```

Comment: @Ridah, Added second solution in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The element `h6.snipe.status span` do not exist on the page.

Try `h6.snipe span`

Also are probably triggering the function before the DOM gets ready. You need to trigger the function after the element on the DOM is ready.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('h6.snipe span').text(function(_,txt) {
    return txt.replace('ÖNE ÇIKANLARI', '');
  });
})
```

Comment: Same result, no error but the sentence still shows, you may view the page source to see where the function is.